# Updating html content in tooltipster after AJAX success

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltipster

I have interactive html content in a tooltipster which is opened when clicking a trigger icon. After submitting data via AJAX I want the content of the tooltip to be replaced with the returned `data`.
Whilst the returned data is shown, the tooltip has at this point closed and only becomes visible when hovering over the original opening trigger.

This is my jQuery for the tooltipster:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".layout-save").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();     
        var form = $(".image_define");
        var params = form.serializeArray();
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('default_image', $('#default_image')[0].files[0]);

        $(params).each(function (index, element) {
            formData.append(element.name, element.value);
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            method: "post",
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            $('.tooltip-imageHandler-<?php echo $products_filter; ?>').tooltipster('destroy');
            $('.tooltip-imageHandler-<?php echo $products_filter; ?>').tooltipster({ 
                content: data,
                contentAsHTML: 'true'
            });
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert('Ajax Submit for New Image Save Failed ...'); 
        });
    });
});
```

I assume it's `.tooltipster('destroy')` that is closing the tooltip, but if I try to replace the content without using `destroy` first, I get an error saying

> Tooltipster: one or more tooltips are already attached to the element
>   below. Ignoring.

Is it possible to replace my content without the tooltipster closing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of others who may want to do this, I resolved the problem like this:

```
.done(function(data) {
            $('.tooltip-imageHandler-<?php echo $products_filter; ?>').tooltipster('destroy');
            $('.tooltip-imageHandler-<?php echo $products_filter; ?>').tooltipster({ 
            content: data,
            contentAsHTML: 'true',
            interactive: 'true'
            });
            $('.tooltip-imageHandler-<?php echo $products_filter; ?>').tooltipster('open');
            $('.tooltip-imageHandler-<?php echo $products_filter; ?>').tooltipster('reposition');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The tooltipster documentation has an update method 'content', the 2nd parameter can pass your settings or just a line of new text.
Example:

```css
.im_tooltip {
  display:block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tooltipster/3.3.0/js/jquery.tooltipster.min.js"></script>

<div class="im_tooltip" title="I'm default init tooltip">Hover me</div>

<button class="change" type="button">Update tooltip</button>

<script>
  $('.im_tooltip').tooltipster();

  $('.change').on('click', function(){
    $('.im_tooltip').tooltipster('content', 'I am change content in tooltip');
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$('.tooltip-imageHandler-<?php echo $products_filter; ?>').tooltipster('update', data);`

Comment: That gives an error in console of Uncaught Error: Unknown method "update"

Comment: https://github.com/iamceege/tooltipster/issues/370   Refer the link. There you have your answer

Comment: As shown in the original question, I already tried .tooltipster('content', 'new content'), but that doesn't work without first clearing the original content. The problem with using 'destroy' is that the tooltip closes when this is fired. Adding 'reposition' doesn't help as the tooltip is still closed and only shows the replaced content when you hover over the trigger icon. The method MAY be usable if there is a way to force the tooltip to reopen as soon as the content has been replaced.